# onChangeText of InputField issue in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a ReactNative application. I have some input fields, on button click if any of these fields is empty i have to show validation error. My code is:

```
<View>
        <InputField placeholder="Teilnummer"
          onChangeText={(nm)=>  this.setState({pTeilnummer: nm})}
        />
        <View>
        {
          this.state.ErrorTeilnummer ? <Text style={styles.ValidationErrorMessage}> * Required </Text> : null
        }
        </View>

        <InputField placeholder="Teilbenennung"
          onChangeText={(nm)=>  this.setState({pTeilbenennung: nm})}
        />
        <View>
        {
          this.state.ErrorTeilbenennung ? <Text style={styles.ValidationErrorMessage}> * Required </Text> : null
        }
        </View>

        <InputField placeholder="Lieferant"
          onChangeText={(nm)=>   this.setState({pLieferant: nm})}
        />
        <View>
        {
          this.state.ErrorLieferant ? <Text style={styles.ValidationErrorMessage}> * Required </Text> : null
        }
        </View>

<Button title="Speichern" color="#ee7100" onPress={() => { this._addProject(this.state.pTeilnummer +  "_" + this.state.pTeilbenennung + "_" +  this.state.pLieferant, this.state.pdate)}}/>
</View>
```

I have declared these states as:

```
constructor(props){
this.state = {ErrorTeilbenennung: false, ErrorTeilnummer: false, ErrorLieferant: false pTeilbenennung: null, pTeilnummer: null, pLieferant: null};
```

My button click code is:

```
_addProject = (name, date) =>{

  teilbenennung = this.state.pTeilbenennung;
  teilnummer = this.state.pTeilnummer;
  lieferant = this.state.pLieferant;
  var selectedCheck = this.state.addCheck

  if(teilbenennung == null || teilnummer == null || lieferant == null)
  {
    if(teilbenennung == null)
      this.setState({ErrorTeilbenennung: true})
    else
      this.setState({ErrorTeilbenennung: false})

    if(teilnummer == null)
      this.setState({ErrorTeilnummer: true})
    else
      this.setState({ErrorTeilnummer: false})

    if(lieferant == null)
      this.setState({ErrorLieferant: true})
    else
      this.setState({ErrorLieferant: false})
  }
  else
  { // saving to database
  }
}
```

When i click on the button first time i get the required validation errors. But after i type something in the first InputField and presses the button, i still get the validation error against that field (may be there is some issue with "onChangeText"), but if i click the button again then the validation error against that field is removed (i mean i have to click twice). Let me add one more thing, when i click on the InputField to write something in it the component reloads. How can i remove this issue so that it works fine with single click

Comment: where is `local_p_id ` and `projects `

Comment: These were simple objects, i have edited the question

Comment: My understanding is that there is some issue with "InputField", after writing something in it, you have to click somewhere else so that it can lose the focus, only after that it will work (will store the value in the state) @hongdevelop

Comment: Can you try changing all the status  values  of NULL to blank?

Comment: the conditional statement for clicking a button should also be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that my view was inside **KeyboardAwareScrollView**, so the first click closes the keyboard, that's why my button click does not trigger on first click. This can be resolved in two ways:

- Use **ScrollView** instead of **KeyboardAwareScrollView**
- Set **keyboardShouldPersistTaps** to **true** like this:

  `<KeyboardAwareScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}>`

Answer (score 1):

I made an example to solve your problem. This is how you solve the problem you want.

Comparing the status values separately is a very inconvenient way. We can solve this problem sufficiently through `onChangeText`

**Example**   is here [ExampleLink](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/textinput-onchangetext-exam)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, TextInput,View,Text,Button } from 'react-native';

export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      text: '',error1 : "error1" ,
     text2: '',error2 : "error2" };
  }

  checkfunc() {
    if(this.state.text !== '' && this.state.text2 !== ''){
      alert("sucess");
    } else {
      alert("faild");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:"center" , justifyContent:"center"}}>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
      {this.state.text !== ''  ? null : (<Text>{this.state.error1}</Text>)}
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text2) => this.setState({text2})}
        value={this.state.text2}
      />
      {this.state.text2 !== ''  ? null : (<Text>{this.state.error2}</Text>)}
      <Button title="checkinput" onPress={() => this.checkfunc()}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => UselessTextInput);
```

Comment: thanks, you mean i should use "TextInput" and not "InputField" .?? because up till now what i have understood is that without losing focus "InputField" will give empty text

Comment: InputField can also be used because it has onChangeText props like Textinput.